# I don't understand something about Laplace Theorem (binomial distribution)

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Here is what I have for it:

**Laplace's theorem:** Let $S_n$ denote the number of "successes" in $n$ Bernoulli's trials, and let $p$ be the probability of success $p\in(0,1)$. Then

$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R} \text{ | } a < b \text{  } \lim_{n\to\infty} P( a < \frac{ S_n - np }{\sqrt{np(1-p)} } < b) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{a}^{b}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt $

I have difficulty understanding what does the condition $a < \frac{ S_n - np }{\sqrt{np(1-p)} } < b$ mean. Basically I'm looking for a way to state this theorem informally (written in words). 
Please keep in mind that this in my book gets introduced way before random variables, variance, expected value and normal distribution so they should not be included.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You seem to know the theorem addresses an idea that a binomial distribution approximates a normal distribution as the sample size $n$ tends to infinity.  Details of the condition $a < \frac{ S_n - np }{\sqrt{np(1-p)} } < b$ are necessary to relate the binomial probability to a probability given by the  normal distribution.  Random variable $S_n$ is being shifted (so as the mean will be zero) and scaled so that the condition expresses a probability that in the limit depends on neither $n$ nor $p$.  Is an explanation of why that is (or "ought to be") true the kind of Answer you are looking for?

Comment: Yep I know that just because i peeked some website before posting the question but both my teacher and book do not mention it.

Comment: If you consult the "Related" Questions that appear on the (desktop) website to the right of yours, you'll see that a number of posts have been written about the approximation of a normal distribution by largish binomial distributions.  As your studies have not yet reached the topic of continuous probability distributions, it is at present only a "nuts-and-bolts" statement of this approximation that can be given, but it may motivate later developments in the same class.  It might help to mention what textbook you are using.

Comment: I'm using "Note di Calcolo delle Probabilità" by Giuseppe Modica and Laura Poggiolini but I doubt this could be relevant.

Comment: I don't think you'll get all that much intuition out of this until you can understand that the fluctuation in $S_n$ scales like $\sqrt{n}$ (which means that $P(|S_n-np| \geq a \sqrt{n})$ converges to a number in $(0,1)$, depending on $a$ and $p$). This is highly non-obvious if you don't have the notion of variance; all you can really understand without that is that it must grow slower than $n$ so that $S_n/n$ can converge to $p$.

Comment: I'm confident that I can walk you through an intuitive understanding of the limit that you ask about above.  There is a history to this result (see [DeMoivre-Laplace Thm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) in Wikipedia for an outline and references), and perhaps taking a look at that and at the previous Questions already suggested ("Related") will help to sharpen your curiousity.

Comment: @hardmath: Hi, I had already seen that page before posting but it makes use of concept I still haven't studied (random variables, variance and expected value, normal distribution) so I can't get what I wish from that. 

Still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Books gives this (translated) description of your textbook, "Note di Calcolo della Probabilità" by Giuseppe Modica and Laura Poggiolini:

> This book collects the topics covered in Probability and Mathematical and Probabilistic Methods held by the authors within the three-year degree courses in Engineering of the University of Florence for use by students. The text presents a set of interesting topics for applications and usable with the basic knowledge of mathematics. The volume, divided into 27 chapters (4 of which are referenced), contains an elementary discussion of the following topics: elementary probability: combinatorial calculation, Bayes formula, inclusion-exclusion formula, random variables: calculation of the associated distributions, distribution joint, independent random variables, sequences of independent random variables: Bernoulli process, large numbers law and central limit theorem, stochastic matrices, discrete time Markov chains and discrete states, Poisson process, continuous time Markov chains and been finished. The central limit theorem is discussed but not demonstrated. The rest of the material is presented with ample details and is accompanied by numerous exercises, many of which carried out.

No preview is available in Google Books, but we may guess that the proposition asked about is included in the book's discussion of *Bernoulli process*.  Although here attributed as "Laplace's theorem", the idea was proposed by [Abraham DeMoivre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_de_Moivre) as early as 1733, to approximate a sum of consecutive terms from a *binomial expansion* by an integral form.  This is quite early in the development of calculus; DeMoivre was a younger contemporary and friend of Isaac Newton himself.

The setup here is that of $n$ [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial), each with an independent chance of "success" $p\in (0,1)$ or of "failure" $1-p$.  The random variable $S_n$ counts the total number of successes, so that $0 \le S_n \le n$ is certain.

Intuitively the average number of successes will be $np$, since each trial has chance $p$ of succeeding independently of the other trials.  You disclaim having been introduced to the notion of *expected value*, but that is the same in this context as the average $S_n$ if we were to repeat those $n$ Bernoulli trials over and over again.  So the outcome described in your Question:

$$ a \lt \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \lt b $$

says that in a particular run, $S_n$ differed from its average value $np$ in a way that the ratio shown falls into the interval $(a,b)$.  It may be easier to interpret if we clear the denominator, i.e. get this equivalent outcome:

$$ a\sqrt{np(1-p)} \lt S_n - np \lt b\sqrt{np(1-p)} $$

Asking about $P\left(a \lt \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \lt b \right)$ means the *probability* that the fraction falls into the range $(a,b)$.  Intuitively the shorter the interval $(a,b)$, the smaller this probability should be.

We find by experience that $S_n - np$ is *more likely* to be close to zero than far away from zero.  That is, the highest "peak" of probability occurs when the interval $(a,b)$ of any specified length $b-a$ is centered around the origin $0$.  A picture contributed to Wikimedia by [user Cflm001](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Cflm001) for $n=$ and $p=0.5$, e.g. flipping a fair coin six times:

[image: Binomial PDF and normal approximation for n = 6 and p = 0.5]

illustrates the strong peaking that occurs around the middle (average) of the outcomes.

The DeMoivre-Laplace theorem says that as $n$ increases to infinity, the chunky bar graph of the binomial probabilities will resemble a *smooth* function familiar to many as "the Bell curve", but called by mathematicians a [Gaussian curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) or "normal distribution".

For an introductory study of mathematical probability, especially one aimed not at "theorem and proof" understanding but on applications useful to engineering undergraduates, this attempt to say exactly how the chunky (discrete) graphs resemble (converge to) a smooth (continuous) graph will be more than a little awkward.  The version you ask about:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} P\left(a \lt \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \lt b \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{a}^{b}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt $$

seems to me to strike an admirable balance between precision and simplicity, but at the expense of confronting the student with an expression difficult to parse because of unfamiliarity.

To finish let's note that the characteristics we discussed above about the Bernoulli outcomes are shared with the limiting *integral* on the right hand side.  First, the closer $a$ and $b$ are, the shorter the interval of integration, and thus the smaller the value of "probability" it gives us.  Second, for any fixed length of that interval of integration, the largest value will be obtained by centering the interval $(a,b)$ around the largest values of the integrand:

$$ e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} $$

which is an even function of $t$ that "peaks" (reaches its maximum) at the origin $t=0$.

Leave a Comment if what I've said needs further clarification.

Comment: My biggest problem here is that I have difficulty figuring out what $ \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} $ is trying to mean, I seem not being able to get an interpretation for it...

Comment: So $S_n - np$ is the difference between the number of "successful" trials actually counted and the average number of these.  E.g. when you flip a fair coin $3600$ times, we expect "about" $1800$ of them to come up heads.  So in that example (which is the one Abraham DeMoivre used as an illustration 280 years ago), the expression tells us how to estimate the chance your result will be close or far away from the average.  The values $a,b$ can be chosen to be close to zero (the most likely outcomes) or far away from zero (the least likely outcomes).

Comment: Yeah I understood that but what's the meaning of the denominator?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Okay, the denominator is the scale we need to make the "chunky" binomial distribution (on the left hand side) most closely approach the unit Gaussian distribution on the right hand side.  When you complete studies in your textbook you will know what a "standard deviation" is, and this is what a mathematician would call the denominator.